# GPRS and GPS on embedded Linux

Tags: gps, embedded-linux, gprs, multiplexing

I've got an embedded linux and a Telit gprs/gps module ("GM862-GPS" on USB-Port). My current project requires it to be connected via gprs for sending data, while continuously asking the module for the gps position. I'm connected to gprs with a ppp-daemon and chatsripts, but when the connection is established, the module seems to be locked (no reaction on AT-commands through minicom).

I read, that 'AT+CMUX' could be one solution, which is provided by this device, but I don't know how to use it, since the 'CMUX User Guide' by Telit isn't really helpfull (and a program for automatic setup is only provided for windows).

Does anyone know, how to deal with this command, or even knows a better choice to handle this problem ?

Comment: Perhaps you can run the windows configuration program and capture the commands it sends.

Answer (score 1):

My answer might be too late.

You need to use CMUX to create another COM port to talk to it. I played with CMUX once and I understand your frustrations. In my case, it worked for a while and then failed and I couldn't find out why. You might want to post your question at Roundsolutions.

I programmed the module by writing Python scripts and upload to the module. Their Python API provides two channels to send AT commands to the module: MDM and MDM2. I use MDM as the AT command and use MDM2 to create sockets. Initially, you use MDM2 to send AT commands to create a socket connection. Once connected, whatever data sent to it will be interpreted as data stream instead of AT commands. They allow you to send '+++' to switch back to AT command mode.